# How to use the GeoServer REST api to get a PNG representation of a layer?

Tags: geoserver, raster, rest, geoserver-rest-api

Does anybody know if I can retrieve by REST service in GeoServer an raster representation of layer?
Just like in for ex. ArcGIS REST Api:
When I send:

```
MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png8&bbox=338477.336%2C360036.34849999996%2C619993.648%2C548154.8615&bboxSR=2180&imageSR=2180&size=1064%2C711&f=image
```

In response, I get png image of layer in defined bbox.

Comment: I think you need ArcServer for that to work - GeoServer's REST is for configuration changes.

Comment: yes I agree I get same response from Geoserver-mailing list.

Answer (score 5):

you have to go through `geoserver`'s wms service:

```
    http://GEOSERVERBASE/geoserver/wms?
    service=WMS&
    version=1.1.1&
    request=GetMap&
    layers=jantrik:Storm_Mains&
    styles=&format=image/png&
    TRANSPARENT=TRUE&
    srs=EPSG:2000&
    bbox=11879566.92588,7000626.9713143,11880134.841974,7001041.8162735&
    width=512&
    height=374
```

You can change the parameters like two layers altogether, bbox, style or others:

```
layers=jantrik:Storm_Mains,jantrik:Storm_Nodes,.....
```

In multiple layers you have to keep in mind that all layers should be in same bbox.

If you don't want to set all the parameters, you can send a request like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=jantrik:Storm_Mains
```

In this request all parameters will be set as default values.
You can give a look at [Geoserver rest api documentation.](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

What @Iant said. As the [GeoServer RESTful interface docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/) says:

> GeoServer provides a RESTful interface through which clients **can
>   retrieve information about an instance and make configuration
>   changes**. Using the REST interface’s simple HTTP calls, clients can
>   configure GeoServer without needing to use the Web Administration
>   Interface.

So unfortunately, you can't really use it to get representations of a layer. However, you can use GeoServer's [web map service](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/reference.html) for that. What you can do is issue a GetMap request like so:

```
http://yourdomain.com/geoserver/wms?
&service=WMS&version=1.1.1
&request=GetMap
&layers=jantrik:Storm_Mains
&styles=&format=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
&srs=EPSG:2000
&bbox=11879566.92588,7000626.9713143,11880134.841974,7001041.8162735
&width=512
&height=374
```

I hope that helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you've been mislead by naming here.

[REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) is mostly thought of as a way to interact with resources over HTTP, by using HTTP verbs (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE).

The WMS-standard is described as RESTful (but if it's actually RESTful is another question).

Thus, your question can be interpreted as "is it possible to get a map image from Geoserver using REST?" In that case the answer is a loud YES: Using the WMS standard as described by R.K.

But, then, as our friends in ESRI decided to create their own "standard", the "ArcGIS REST API", which I think of as a "kind-of-wms" and then the confusion sets in.

Because, as you've apparently found out, GeoServer also has a REST api (in addition to the "WMS api"). But this Geoserver-specific API operates on Geoserver itself (not the Web Map Service it offers). So, using the "Geoserver REST API" it's not possible to get a map image, but that was never the intention eiter, as Geoserver serves map images using WMS.

Hope this clears things up!